# Prevent listing hosted domain under IP

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

When I enter my public IP with one of my hosted domains, folders appear, such as public_html etc.

It is ok, when I enter just www.domain.com, since I configured DocumentRoot directly to public_html.

But the case is when external IP is entered, such as 66.77.88.99/domain.com

I tried to place .htaccess to the same directory where public_html to prevent indexing, but no result.

Answer (score 0):

```
66.77.88.99/domain.com
```

...points to your default vhost.

Just change document root in default vhost config to:

```
/xxx/xxx/public_html/
```

or disable the default vhost.